# What are slabs of screen sizes for developing apps for mobile devices(including tablets) ?

Tags: mobile-application

I am not sure whether my title is clear, so will try to explain here.

Before building an app for mobile, what screen size should i consider first keeping in mind the android fragmentation. For iOS its easy as we know the various possibilities where our app will be consumed. But for Android, if I design for 4" and if my app is consumed at 6" it definitely won't be the experience I intend to provide.

How to arrive at a slab say 3-6", 7-10" and so on where-in the same design can be consumed without impacting the user-experience? Is such a slab even feasible to arrive at?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never heard it referred to as 'slab'. Regardless, what you want to do is responsive design...accommodate them all.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to explicitly design applications separately for the smaller screens say 3" to 6" and for tabs screen size say 7" to 10" to give the user the best of both the worlds (and users love that).

[Here's an amazing article from smashingmagazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/30/designing-for-android/) about **designing for android devices**.

I personally, for mobile android, design for 1280 x 720 resolution (4.8" screen), which can be easily translated into an inch smaller or larger screen.

[You may also have a look at the official android doc for further reference.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't want to design based on inches but rather on actual screen pixel dimensions (while accounting for high density displays)